# Eloquent One To Many issue

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

i have a question related to the title.
so i have this models (i have more code and models behind if u need tell me)

Cliente Model

```
protected $table = 'cliente';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_cliente';
public $timestamps = false;

public function seguroCarro()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SeguroCarro', 'id_seguro_carro');
}
```

SeguroCarro Model

```
protected $table = 'seguro_carro';
protected $primaryKey = 'id_seguro_carro';
public $timestamps = false;

public function cliente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'id_cliente');
}
```

Question:

This `Cliente::find(1)->seguroCarro` get the seguro_carro with id 1 and not with id_cliente 1 but this `SeguroCarro::all()->where('id_cliente',Auth::user()->cliente->id_cliente)` get the 3 rows seguro_carro i need

i dont get why this happen but i want understand why

**Atencion:**
this `Cliente::find(1)->seguroCarro` is a abreviation for you guys for my code `Auth::user()->cliente->seguroCarro` [my Auth::user()->cliente have the id 1]

[img of rows on seguro_carro table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7hsZ.jpg)

Thank you for the time guys

Comment: Try this: Auth::user()->seguroCarro()->get()

Comment: i try Auth::user()->seguroCarro()->get(), Auth::user()->cliente()->seguroCarro()->get() , nothing im using the SeguroCarro::all()->where('id_cliente',Auth::user()->cliente->id_cliente) like i say until a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship on your `App\Cliente` model is specifying the wrong key. The second parameter to the `hasOne`/`hasMany` relationship is the name of the foreign key field on the related object. In this case, the foreign key on the related object (`App\SeguroCarro`) is `id_cliente`, not `id_seguro_carro`.

Your current relationship will get the `seguro_carro` records `where seguro_carro.id_seguro_carro = cliente.id_cliente`, which is not what you want.

The relationship should be changed to:

```
public function seguroCarro()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SeguroCarro', 'id_cliente');
}
```

This will get the `seguro_carro` records `where seguro_carro.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente`, which is what you want.

The `belongsTo` relationship on your `App\SeguroCarro` is correct.